# Subquery inside a view is not working corectly

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating view to be used in FastReport(ReportingSoftware) and I have a sub-query in the form of a scalar-Valued Function inside this to pull together the full address of a property, Though it is bringing back the error Subquery returned more than 1 value and I'm not sure why, I have used something similar to this in the past cant seem to figure out the issue.

Here is my View Code

```
SELECT  TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.PropertyMaster.PropertyID, 
        dbo.Lookup_PropertyManager.Description, dbo.Lookup_PropertyManager.Email, 
        dbo.GetFullAddress(dbo.PropertyMaster.PropertyID) AS FullAddress, 
        dbo.Tenants.TenantID, dbo.Tenants.LeaseID, 
        dbo.Tenants.TenantForeName + ' ' + dbo.Tenants.TenantSurname AS FullName, 
        dbo.PropertyMaster.SPMReference, 
        CONVERT(varchar, dbo.PropertyLease.StartDate,101) AS StartDate, 
        CONVERT(varchar, dbo.PropertyLease.DateSigned, 101) AS DateSigned
FROM  dbo.PropertyLease 
      RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.PropertyMaster 
             ON dbo.PropertyLease.PropertyID = dbo.PropertyMaster.PropertyID 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Tenants 
             ON dbo.PropertyMaster.PropertyID = dbo.Tenants.PropertyID 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Lookup_PropertyManager 
    ON dbo.PropertyMaster.PropertyManagerID = dbo.Lookup_PropertyManager.PropertyManagerID
ORDER BY dbo.PropertyMaster.PropertyID
```

and here is my scalar-Valued Function

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetFullAddress] 
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    (@PropertyID as integer )
RETURNS varchar(250) 
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @AddressLine as varchar(40)
DECLARE @FullAddress as varchar(250)
SET @FullAddress = (SELECT LTRIM(ISNULL(TenantForeName + ' ', ' ') + TenantSurname) AS FullName FROM Tenants  WHERE PropertyID = @PropertyID) + CHAR(10)


SET @AddressLine = (SELECT ISNULL(AddressLine1, '') FROM PropertyMaster WHERE PropertyID = @PropertyID)
SET @FullAddress = @FullAddress + @AddressLine + CHAR(10)
        SET @AddressLine = (SELECT  ISNULL(AddressLine2, '') FROM PropertyMaster WHERE PropertyID = @PropertyID)
IF @AddressLine <> ''
    BEGIN
        SET @FullAddress = @FullAddress + @AddressLine + CHAR(10)
    END
        SET @AddressLine = (SELECT  ISNULL(AddressLine3, '') FROM PropertyMaster WHERE PropertyID = @PropertyID)
IF @AddressLine <> ''
    BEGIN
        SET @FullAddress = @FullAddress + @AddressLine + CHAR(10)
    END
SET @AddressLine = (SELECT ISNULL(Town, '' ) FROM PropertyMaster WHERE PropertyID = @PropertyID)
IF @AddressLine <> ''
    BEGIN
        SET @FullAddress = @FullAddress + @AddressLine + CHAR(10)
    END
SET @AddressLine = (SELECT ISNULL(PostCode, '') FROM PropertyMaster WHERE PropertyID = @PropertyID)
SET @FullAddress = @FullAddress + @AddressLine

RETURN @FullAddress
END
```

Comment: are you checked scalar function work correctly independent? Where exactly you getting error, in view or function

Comment: Yes I have used this function before in other places and executes successfully  ... I am getting the error in the view side .

Comment: The `Subquery returned more than 1 value` error is pretty simple: it means your subquery (one or more) returned more than one value. You'll need to take the `@PropertyId` that the function fails on and run each subquery to see which returns more than one result, then figure out how to fix your data or refactor your code. I've gotten this error many times, and each time it is because there is a subquery returning more than one value.

Comment: try to remove this function call from view, and see if view if working fine or not with function call....?then you easily figure out there is no connection of function with error

Comment: ah sorry yeah I have tried this and the view works with out the function

Comment: I think there are more than one tenant for a propertyID. But of course You must check if isn't more then one record in propertymaster to one propertyid.

Comment: Yeah I have Checked this also, the view itself Should bring back a list of records that will contain the same PropertyID?

Comment: Try run this: `SELECT PropertyID FROM Tenants group by PropertyID having count(1)>1`. I think You get some result.

Comment: If this is going to return a lot of rows, you probably will have serious performance issues. I would recommend changing the function to a inline table valued function (yes, it requires different kind of coding) or at least fetching the data from PropertyMaster once instead of 5 different fetches with the same key.

Comment: Side note: `TOP 100 PERCENT ... ORDER BY` is a hack and may or may not produce any meaningful sorting of results. The only sound way to guarantee the order in which results are returned in a query is to have an `ORDER BY` on the outermost query (e.g. the one that *uses* this view)

Comment: JamesZ is right about performance.   You are already joining to the tables that you need to get the full address in your view.. You can eliminate the function.. If you just really want to use a function then create a new function that accepts the fields you need as parameters and build the full address from the parameters without hitting the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is most likely this line

```
SET @FullAddress = (SELECT LTRIM(ISNULL(TenantForeName + ' ', ' ') + TenantSurname) AS FullName FROM Tenants  WHERE PropertyID = @PropertyID) + CHAR(10)
```

You can change it to just get the first tenant by adding Top 1

```
SET @FullAddress = (SELECT TOP 1 LTRIM(ISNULL(TenantForeName + ' ', ' ') + TenantSurname) AS FullName FROM Tenants  WHERE PropertyID = @PropertyID) + CHAR(10)
```

Or you can concatenate all of the tenants together.

```
SELECT @FullAddress = COALESCE(@FullAddress, '') 
       + LTRIM(ISNULL(TenantForeName + ' ', ' ') + TenantSurname) AS FullName 
FROM   Tenants  
WHERE  PropertyID = @PropertyID) + CHAR(10)
```

**P.S.**  If this is the issue.  Your view is most like returning duplicate rows since you are left joining to the tenants table also.  If you need a row for each tenant in your view, then you'll probably want to pass in the tenantid to the function and add that as a where clause to the query to get the tenant name.

Comment: Tats just what I was looking for Cheers couldn't spot it at all

Answer (score 1):

**This is not an answer to the question**.
I'm posting it here only since it's almost impossible to read code posted in comments.

In addition to what [user1221684](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1221684/user1221684) wrote in his/hers [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30758458/3094533),
The rest of the function can be written like this:

```
SELECT @FullAddress = @FullAddress + CHAR(10) +
       ISNULL(AddressLine1 + CHAR(10), '')  +
       ISNULL(AddressLine2 + CHAR(10), '') +
       ISNULL(AddressLine3 + CHAR(10), '') +
       ISNULL(Town + CHAR(10), '' ) + 
       ISNULL(PostCode, '')
FROM PropertyMaster WHERE PropertyID = @PropertyID
```

**Explanation:**
There really is no need to select a different column from the same table 
in more then one query.

In sql server, when you concatenate a string (`char(10)` in this case) to a null value, the result is null. therefor `ISNULL(AddressLine1 + CHAR(10), '')` would return an empty string if `AddressLine1` is null.